# Passing Parameters Between ClassLoaders Via Reflection API

Tags: java, reflection, classloader

I'm using a custom Classloader to create and return an instance of a class, this seems to work ok however when I try to call a method (via the Reflection API) and pass in a custom object as described below I get a `NoSuchMethodException`:

Supposing that the custom class loader creates and returns an instance like so:

```
Object obj = customClassLoader.load(String className,Class[] paramTypes,Object[] param)
```

Then I call a method  (via reflection) and pass in a custom object:

NOTE: THIS IS THE LINE CAUSING THE ERROR

```
Method m = obj.getClass.getDeclaredMethod("mName",new Class[]{aCustomObject.class}) 

m.invoke(obj,new Object[]{new CustomObject() })
```

I'm stumped as to what could be causing the exception since a method definitely does exist which takes the specified custom object, I have confirmed this by using reflection to list all methods.

Comment: Did you try print out all available methods from this class and see if your method present there? Using `getDeclaredMethods`.

Comment: Yes, as mentioned above, I have successfully been able to print out all methods. I'm wondering if its because I'm using two classloaders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How is your custom loader's load() method instantiating the object it is to return? Maybe the `NoSuchMethodException` arises during trying to find the correct constructor?

This example seems to work out OK:

```
package com.pholser;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class ClassLoading {
    public static class CustomLoader extends ClassLoader {
        public Object load(String className, Class<?>[] paramTypes, Object[] params) throws Exception {
            Class<?> loaded = loadClass(className);
            return loaded.getConstructor(paramTypes).newInstance(params);
        }
    }

    public static class ACustomObject {
    }

    public void foo(ACustomObject a) {
        System.out.println("foo");
    }

    public static Object newCustomObject() throws Exception {
        return new CustomLoader().load("com.pholser.ClassLoading$ACustomObject", new Class<?>[0], new Object[0]);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ClassLoading obj = new ClassLoading();

        Method m = obj.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("foo", ACustomObject.class);

        m.invoke(obj, newCustomObject());
    }
}
```

Comment: The last line should be: m.invoke(obj, new CustomObject()); I have updated my question to reflect this. Your example does work as expected and I suspect its because you are creating the new object with the SAME ClassLoader as the one that instantiated the ClassLoading class. In my example I try to pass in an object instantiated by the default classloader.

Comment: Additionally, thank you very much indeed for your detailed answer.